# jQuery onload - click external link & display only particular ID, not full page, within page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is the link:

```
 <a href="1.php#filter=.element007">
```

Now i want 2.php, on load, to display this 1.php's content,

only that content which is inside

```
id="isotope".
```

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, I'd strongly recommend you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works.

Comment: Look guys, m totally new to programming. Rather than , giving negative click, it would be better that u can try to help me. Its jQuery isotope

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work, but only when i manually post the content inside class isotope from 1.php, to class grid of this page. If I use JS, God knows, why it stops working. Any Hints :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".grid").load("1.php .isotope > *");
});
</script>
<script>

$( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
itemSelector: '.element',
layoutMode: 'fitRows' ,
filter: '.lmd'
  });
  });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Isotope - filtering</h1>
<div class="grid"> </div>
<!--- /.grid --->

</body>
</html>
```